# Module for multi-tiered Play 2.0 navigation menu

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm in the process of transitioning a web app from JSPs/Tiles over to Play 2.0.  In our current application, we have a two-tiered horizontal navigation menu.  We get the nice CSS from Bootstrap (and will again) but were using Tiles to deal with the navigation menu logic.  Are there any frameworks for easily wiring together a navigation menu in Play 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Play framework has no any default navigation schema or structure, so there's no abstract module ready for this.

For building Bootsrtap-styled menu all you need to do is to iterate some `List` of items, and wrap it with proper HTML. I don't think if it's required to write any module for that...

Comment: Sort of expected that answer - it just seemed like a very common thing to need so thought there was a ready made module.